# Code after calling a Generator will not run until Generator returns a value

Tags: python, multithreading, generator

I have code that basically replicates Shell's tail -f function as the below:

```
def _read_log(logfile, logger):
    def _generator(logfile):
        with open(f'{logfile}', 'r') as file:
            file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
            while True:
                line = file.readline()
                if not regex_SSH.search(line):
                    sleep(1)
                    continue
                ip = regex_IP.search(line).group()
                logger.warning(f"Failed SSH Login for IP: {ip}")
                yield ip

    for line in _generator(logfile):
        return line
```

What I would like to do is put this in its own separate thread and just have it running over and over. I thought the simple solution would be something like:

```
def main():
    while True:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            executor.submit(_read_log)
            executor.submit(some_other_function)
```

The problem I'm having is, nothing after executor.submit(_read_log) will run UNTIL that generator returns a value, which may take some time. Ideally I need the rest of my code to just keep chugging along even if the generator isn't returning a value. I'm a little stuck on this one, any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a lot here that doesn't make sense. Why are you `return`ing on the first iteration of the `for` loop? Why are you passing no arguments for `_read_log` in the `submit` call? Why use `f'{logfile}'` instead of just `logfile`?

Comment: We need to see a [mcve].